# Understanding the Semigroup. Functional Programming. Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, scala-cats

It's easy to read and understand what the algebra of **Semigroup** is. But for software developer in background of imperative style languages it is still a foggy concept. Unfortunately my studies treated more about pointers than abstract algebra so now my brain is pretty much infected by imperative thinking ... The problem is that I know the definition but I don't get it. It is still not so obvious *where*, *when* and *why* I suppose to create/provide/use semigroups?!

Since general definition (*... Semigroup can combine things together ...*) didn't explain well usages and please could you provide **real world examples** in form of **problem - solution**?

In answers plese include as much as possible below aspects:

- using the `append`/`combine` function
- composing semigroups
- what does the `def apply: Apply[λ[α => F]]` function
- (these come from *spire-math* - a library that *cats* depends on)  what the hek are the

  - `AdditiveSemigroup[A]`
  - `MultiplicativeSemigroup[A]`
  - `CommutativeSemigroup[A]`
  - `AdditiveCommutativeSemigroup[A]`
  - `MultiplicativeCommutativeSemigroup[A]`
  - `Band[A]` - this is *idempotent* semigroup
- what are usages of mentioned above
- what functions/combinators that depend on semigroup do you use (probably functions in form of `def f[A: Semigroup)(a: A) ...` so they see the `Semigroup` as typeclass and use it's behaviour)
- what semigroups do you know and how they behave in context of above functions
- [other aspects that couldn't be mentioned by me cause I don't understand the topic]

**All (partial)answers are warmly welcome! :)**

Merged snippet of Semigroup trait from *scalaz* and *cats*:

```
trait Semigroup[F]  { self =>

  def append(f1: F, f2: => F): F //scalaz
  def combine(x: A, y: A): A     //equivalent of `append` in cats

  // derived functions

  def multiply1(value: F, n: Int): F   //scalaz
  def compose: Compose[λ[(α, β) => F]] //scalaz
  def apply: Apply[λ[α => F]] //scalaz; `λ[α => F]` is the same as `({type λ[α] = α => F})#λ`
  def combineN(a: A, n: Int): A   //cats
  def combineAllOption: Option[A] //cats


  /** Lawes of semigroup - from scalaz:
   * A semigroup in type F must satisfy two laws:
    *
    *  - '''closure''': `∀ a, b in F, append(a, b)` is also in `F`. This is enforced by the type system.
    *  - '''associativity''': `∀ a, b, c` in `F`, the equation `append(append(a, b), c) = append(a, append(b , c))` holds.
   */
}
```